# Why the same id is incremented when I save an object in the repository?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, api, rest

Whenever I call save() method the same ID is shared between three different entities and I don't know why ?

```
@Entity
public class Department {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long departmentId;
    private String name;

    public Department(Long departmentId) {
        this.departmentId = departmentId;
    }

    public Department() {
    }

    public Department(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getDepartmentId() {
        return departmentId;
    }

    public void setDepartmentId(Long departmentId) {
        this.departmentId = departmentId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

@Entity
public class Location {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long locationId;
    private String name;

    public Location(Long locationId) {
        this.locationId = locationId;
    }

    public Location() {
    }

    public Location(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getLocationId() {
        return locationId;
    }

    public void setLocationId(Long locationId) {
        this.locationId = locationId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And this is my Controller:

```
@RestController
public class SettingsController {

    @Autowired
    private LocationRepository locationRepository;
    @Autowired
    private DepartmentRepository departmentRepository;
    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/locations", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity addLocation(@RequestBody DataForm dataForm) {
        if (dataForm == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        locationRepository.save(new Location(dataForm.getName()));
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/roles", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity addRole(@RequestBody DataForm dataForm) {
        if (dataForm == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        roleRepository.save(new Role(dataForm.getName()));
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/departments", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity addDepartment(@RequestBody DataForm dataForm) {
        if (dataForm == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        departmentRepository.save(new Department(dataForm.getName()));
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

This should happen only if the id would be static, but It's not. If I create two new Location() objects, when I will create a new Department() the Id of the department will be 3. Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't specify the strategy for `@GeneratedValue`, I guess that Hibernate uses the same sequence for all your entities.

You can set something like

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="department_seq_gen")
@SequenceGenerator(name="department_seq_gen", sequenceName="DEPARTMENT_SEQ")
```

on `Department` entity, and something similar on `Location` entity (just use `location_seq_gen` and `LOCATION_SEQ`).